# HP DL380 G5 how to add spare disk in Hardware Raid 5

Tags: raid

We have a HP DL380 G5 server with Centos 5.0 on it with hardware raid 5, as one of the disk has failed and spare disk has taken over it's place so we don't have any spare disk in the array. I want to add the spare disk in the array and i want your valuable suggestion how to do that. The machine has 3 SCSI hot pluggable drives.

I know the utility is hpacucli but dont know how to add the disk in the raid. This is my first time i am doing it and server is Live with some critical application.

if any one can let me know steps to add the spare disk including if we need to format the disk with ext3 file system before or after adding the disk.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of hardware RAID and hot-swappable disks is that you pull out the failed disk and stick the new one in and you're done.

It's not clear from your question how many drives you've got, if you've really got only 3 drives and one has failed, you should probably put the replacement disk in soon...

Comment: Agreed.. assuming you have a decent RAID card in your HP, you should be able to pull out the failed drive and slide in a new drive. The controller should automatically pick up the change and mark the new drive as the new spare.

Answer (score 1):

Dell hardware RAID solutions that include hot pluggable backplanes will automatically rebuild in swap.  I use the RAID utilities to verify successful rebuilding.  I cannot specifically speak for HP hardware but I would be shocked if it differs much.

No disk formatting or filesystem creation is necessary.